# No option to install joomla in LAMP (PHP+MSSQL)

Tags: php, joomla, lamp

I have spent a day to find the option to install the joomla in the lamp with SQL Server database connectivity.

In windows also i can see sqlsrv in the dropdown while new joomla installation. but i would like to go with MSSQL Driver.

How to install the joomla in Linux box ( MSSQL + PHP ).

In drop down i dont see the MSSQL option. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

To install Joomla you might have to do a manual install yourself and not use their fancy install scripts. If joomla can use MSSQL with apache on windows, it can use MSSQL on apache on linux. It is just that it is not a common install practice on linux I assume so they haven't bothered to make it an option for their install script. I'm sure someone has done it and provided some online help or you are going to need to rummage around the Joomla docs and do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for advise i am also looking that links only. so far no good luck. lets i cont my research.

Comment: Joomla checks your server to see what is available and only gives you those options it can make connections for.  Check your server and see what you actually have installed or if they are installed somewhere unexpected.  Also I don't believe MSSQL is supported just SQLSrv/Azure.

Comment: yes right now there is no option for MSSQL. looks v have to build.